# mule 3.4.0 spring security with OpenAM

Tags: spring-security, mule, opensso

How do I secure a http endpoint in mule using Spring Security with OpenAM as Authentication Provider? I used

```
<http:inbound-endpoint host="somehost" port="someport" path="myHttp" exchange-pattern="request-response">
 <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm"/>
</http:inbound-endpoint>
```

but the issue I face is that Mule uses DefaultMuleAuthentication whose getCredentials() returns a String while OpenAM is looking for com.iplanet.sso.SSOToken and I get java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.iplanet.sso.SSOToken.