# Mule 3.4.0 Get HTTPRequest object from http inbound endpoint

Tags: httprequest, mule, inbound

I have an http:inbound-endpoint. Is there any way to get a handle to HttpServletRequest object in a Filter/Interceptor? Is ObjectToHttpClientMethodRequest an answer? If so, could someone please provide a sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running Mule in a servlet container, you need to use `servlet:inbound-endpoint`, not `http:inbound-endpoint`.

But even with that, I do not think Mule lets you access the underlying `HttpServletRequest`...

Comment: Thanks David. I was trying to solve the following issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141638/mule-3-4-0-spring-security-with-openam. Thought I can code a bridge since OpenSSO Provider has it's own token which it builds using HTTPServletRequest object.

Comment: Mmh, then I guess your only option consists in creating an HTTPServletRequest adapter for the MuleMessage then.

Comment: Sorry David :( Could you please elaborate a little more? I know I can go through the Open SSO code and find out all the request params that are being used and create a http request wrapper. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Well, I don't really want to send you towards http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/transport/http/servlet/MuleHttpServletRequest.html : see the comment in it. It seems you're on your own :$

Comment: Thanks David. After looking at MuleHttpServletRequest code, which is just boilerplate with no real implementation, it is pretty evident that there is no direct way of getting a HttpServletRequest or it's wrapper. Appreciate your assistance and accepting your answer.